# java_give_question_to_me

Tags: java

I have an aplication where is picture with SIN, COS..
TextArea1 will tell somebody: "Click in picture where SIN"
if user do this, textArea2 tell him: "It is corect"

After that, textArea1.append "Click in picture where COS"
-but program is still waiting for clicking to SIN :(
Can you help me and give a little advice to me please?

There is some code:

```
private class KlikaniMysi implements MouseListener {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getX() + "  " + e.getY());
        //for finding coordinates (by console)
        //textArea2 = "try" at start !!
        //textArea1 = "Find SIN" at start !!!!!!!!
        if(textArea2.equals("try")){
            if( (((e.getX()) > 420)&&((e.getX()) < 580)) && ( ((e.getY()) > 164)&&((e.getY()) < 178) )){
                textArea2.setText("");
                textArea2.append("RIGHT1");
                textArea1.append("Find COS"); //!!!! work!!
                //How to stop the IF cycle here and run class KlikaniMysi (mouselistener) again ?
            }
            else{
                textArea1.setText("");  
                textArea1.append("try again");
            }
        }else{
            if( (((e.getX()) > 586)&&((e.getX()) < 594)) && ( ((e.getY()) > 174)&&((e.getY()) < 282) )){
                //This isnt nice, but I dont know how to expres range better.                        
                textArea1.setText("");
                textArea2.append("Right2");
                textArea1.append("Find  TAN");
            }
            else{
                vystup.setText("");  
                textArea1.append("Try again");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many more aspects about this code that are 'suboptimal' but I think your problem is here:

```
if(textArea2.equals("try"))
```

You want to test the content of that area, not the area itself, hence change it to

```
if(textArea2.getText().equals("try"))
```